# For what values of x is the linear approximation $\sqrt{x + 3} \simeq \frac74 + \frac x4 $accurate to within 0.5?

Tags: linearization

For what values of x is the linear approximation $\sqrt{x + 3} \simeq \frac74 + \frac x4 $accurate to within 0.5?

**My Try**

I found this question under llinearization lesson
Since this problem does not mention about a point around which it is approximated, I took it as 'a'

$\therefore$ $f(x)=f(a)+(x-a) f'(a)$

$f(x)=\sqrt{a+3} + \frac{x-a}{2\sqrt{x+3}}$

How do I proceed to find 'a' such that the error is within 0.5? Please Help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You could try to solve $$\sqrt{x + 3} = \frac74 + \frac x4 +\frac12$$ and $$\sqrt{x + 3} = \frac74 + \frac x4 -\frac12$$ which if you square both sides will give you two quadratics and possibly some spurious solutions to check.  Then spot the relevant intervals

Comment: Doesn't it have to be an inequilaity? |f(x)-L(x)|<0.5

Comment: @emil yes it does, but the solutions will be in the relevant intervals.  As a further tip, the first equation does not seem to have real roots

Comment: Interesting! that's because the function is concave down..Thanks a lot

Comment: @emil: I would say it is because $\left(\frac{x-1}{4}\right)^2 = \left(\frac74 + \frac x4\right)^2-(x+3)$ so $\sqrt{x + 3} \le  \frac74 + \frac{x}4 \, \forall x \ge -3$